# PHP Array str_replace Whole Word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace, word-boundary

I'm doing `str_replace` on a very long `string` and my `$search` is an `array`.

```
$search = array(
    " tag_name_item ",
    " tag_name_item_category "
);

$replace = array(
    " tag_name_item{$suffix} ",
    " tag_name_item_category{$suffix} "
);

echo str_replace($search, $replace, $my_really_long_string);
```

The reason why I added spaces on both `$search` and `$replace` is because I want to only match whole words. As you would have guessed from my code above, if I removed the spaces and my really long string is:

```
...
tag_name_item ...
tag_name_item_category ...
...
```

Then I would get something like

```
...
tag_name_item_sfx ...
tag_name_item_sfx_category ...
...
```

This is wrong because I want the following result:

```
...
tag_name_item_sfx ...
tag_name_item_category_sfx ...
...
```

#### So what's wrong?

Nothing really, it works. But I don't like it. Looks dirty, not well coded, inefficient.

I realized I can do something like this using regular expressions using the `\b` modifier but I'm not good with regex and so I don't know how to `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach using regular expressions would/could look like this:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/\b(tag_name_item(_category)?)\b/',
    '$1' . $suffix,
    $string
);
```

How it works:

- `\b`: As you say are word boundaries, this is to ensure we're only matching words, not word parts
- `(`: We want to use part of our match in the replacement string (`tag_name_index` has to be replaced with itself + a suffix). That's why we use a match group, so we can refer back to the match in the replacement string
- `tag_name_index` is a literal match for that string.
- `(_category)?`: Another literal match, grouped and made optional through use of the `?` operator. This ensures that we're matching both `tag_name_item` and `tag_name_item_category`
- `)`: end of the first group (the optional `_category` match is the second group). This group, essentially, holds the entire match we're going to replace
- `\b`: word boundary again

These matches are replaced with `'$1' . $suffix`. The `$1` is a reference to the first match group (everything inside the outer brackets in the expression). You could refer to the second group using `$2`, but we're not interested in that group right now.

That's all there is to it really

---

### More generic:

So, you're trying to suffix all strings starting with `tag_name`, which judging by your example, can be followed by any number of snake_cased words. A more generic regex for that would look something like this:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/\b(tag_name[a-z_]*)\b/',
    '$1' . $suffix,
    $string
);
```

Like before, the use of `\b`, `()` and the `tag_name` literal remains the same. what changed is this:

- `[a-z_]*`: This is a character class. It matches characters a-z (a to z), and underscores zero or more times (`*`). It matches `_item` and `_item_category`, just as it would match `_foo_bar_zar_fefe`.

These regex's are *case-sensitive*, if you want to match things like `tag_name_XYZ`, you'll probably want to use the `i` flag (case-insensitive): `/\b(tag_name[a-z_]*)\b/i`

Like before, the entire match is grouped, and used in the replacement string, to which we add `$suffix`, whatever that might be

Comment: This is very specific to the example I gave, could you make it more generic so that it doesn't restrict itself to `category`? Basically I just want to append the `$suffix` to all the words that start with `tag_name`.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio: Updated my answer, added a more generic expression + explained what the expression does a bit

Comment: This works! Thank you! And a hug from me for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem, you can use `strtr` that parses the string only once and chooses the longest match:

```
$pairs = [ " tag_name_item "          => " tag_name_item{$suffix} ",
           " tag_name_item_category " => " tag_name_item_category{$suffix} " ];

$result = strtr($str, $pairs);
```